# Position absolute for <img/> when using xhtml2pdf (Django)?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation, xhtml2pdf

Can I generate PDF with CSS `position: absolute;` for `<img src="..."/>` html tag?

I need to place handwritten signature and company stamp (PNG files) to bottom of order voucher at non standard place, that they run a little on the goods table. Position `absolute` will save my time for that, but it's don't working.

**EDIT:**

I have an answer from [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/387#issuecomment-367728736) GitHub repo:

> Well absolute position **is not supported right now**, but if you are looking for how to set images in specific part of page in all pages, see **frames**.

So, my question is still actual. *Real* usage example with `xhtml2pdf` frames for images will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And *real* usage example from Luis Zárate (`xhtml2pdf` collaborator):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
        @frame content_frame {          /* Content Frame */
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
        }
        @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
            -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
            left: 450pt; width: 300pt; top: 672pt; height: 200pt;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Content for Static Frame 'footer_frame' -->
    <div id="footer_content">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/123px-Tux.svg.png?download">
    </div>

    {% lorem 10 p %} 
    <pdf:pdf-next-page />
    {% lorem 10 p %}
</body>
</html>
```

Code generates this PDF file: https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/files/1754033/report-7.pdf